# Spinner dropdown setOnItemSelectedListener not responding

Tags: android

**Java code,** I does display correctly, but, when clicking nothing happens, I am on Android Studio API 31, SDK31. Provided the entire code below for the only activity that exists. I hope this is enough, for someone to notice.

I really don't know, why the `setOnItemSelectedListener` is not working properly here. And the `Spinner downdown` does not respond when clicking on it.

```
package com.eren0045.thirtythrows;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.eren0045.thirtythrows.classes.Die;
import com.eren0045.thirtythrows.classes.ThirtyThrowsGame;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 *
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView[] m_DieButtons;
    private Button m_rollButton;
    private Spinner m_scoreChoiceDropdown;
    private TextView m_scoreChoiceText;
    private TextView m_scoreText;

    private ThirtyThrowsGame m_game = new ThirtyThrowsGame();
    private Map<ImageView, Die> m_dice = new HashMap<>();

    private enum STATE { GAME, NOTIFICATION, SELECTED_MODE }

    private final int[] activeDiceImages = {0,
            R.drawable.white, R.drawable.white1, R.drawable.white2,
            R.drawable.white3, R.drawable.white4, R.drawable.white5, R.drawable.white6
    };

    private final int[] inactiveDiceImages = { 0,
            R.drawable.grey1, R.drawable.grey2, R.drawable.grey3,
            R.drawable.grey4, R.drawable.grey5, R.drawable.grey6
    };

    private final int[] finishedDiceImages = { 0,
            R.drawable.red1, R.drawable.red2, R.drawable.red3,
            R.drawable.red4, R.drawable.red5, R.drawable.red6
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Initialize();
        if(savedInstanceState == null)
            SetStartValues();
    }

/*    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        outState.putString(STATE.NOTIFICATION.toString(), m_scoreChoiceText.getText().toString());
        outState.putString(STATE.SELECTED_MODE.toString(), m_scoreChoiceDropdown.getSelectedItem().toString());

        outState.putParcelable(STATE.GAME.toString(), m_game);
        for(ImageView dieImage : m_dice.keySet()){
            outState.putParcelable("" + dieImage.getId(), m_dice.get(dieImage));
        }

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        m_game = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(STATE.GAME.toString());
        ArrayList<Die> dice = m_game.getDice();
        for(int i = 0; i < m_DieButtons.length; i++)
            m_dice.put(m_DieButtons[i], dice.get(i));

        RefreshAllDieImageViews();
        InitializeDropdown();

        if(!m_game.hasStarted())
            SetStartValues();
        else if(m_game.isRoundScored()){ }
        else if(m_game.isRoundOver()){ }
        else { }

        ThirtyThrowsGame.ScoreChoice selectedScore = ThirtyThrowsGame.ScoreChoice.valueOf(savedInstanceState.getString(STATE.SELECTED_MODE.toString()));
        int chosenScoreIndex = m_game.getAvailableScoreChoices().indexOf(selectedScore);
        m_scoreChoiceDropdown.setSelection(chosenScoreIndex);
        m_scoreChoiceText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(STATE.NOTIFICATION.toString()));

        RefreshRollButtonText();
    }*/

    private void SetStartValues() 
    {
        m_game = new ThirtyThrowsGame();
        
        ArrayList<Die> gameDice = m_game.getDice();
        for(int i = 0; i < gameDice.size(); i++){
            m_DieButtons[i].setEnabled(false);
            m_dice.put(m_DieButtons[i], gameDice.get(i));
        }
        InitializeDropdown();
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    private void RefreshAllDieImageViews()
    {
        if(!m_game.hasStarted())
            return;
        for(ImageView view : m_dice.keySet()) {
            RefreshDieImageView(view);
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param view
     */
    private void RefreshDieImageView(ImageView view)
    {
        Die current = m_dice.get(view);
        int ID;
        int value = current.getValue();

        if(m_game.isRoundOver())
        {
            view.setEnabled(false);
            ID = finishedDiceImages[value];
        }
        else {
            ID = current.isEnabled() ? activeDiceImages[value] : inactiveDiceImages[value];
        }

        view.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, ID));
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    private void RefreshRollButtonText()
    {
        String rollText;
        rollText = m_game.isRoundOver() ? "Roll!" : "Roll (" + m_game.geTotalRollsLeft() + ")";
        m_rollButton.setText(rollText);
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    private void Initialize() {
       m_DieButtons = new ImageView[] {
               findViewById(R.id.die1),
               findViewById(R.id.die2),
               findViewById(R.id.die3),
               findViewById(R.id.die4),
               findViewById(R.id.die5),
               findViewById(R.id.die6)
       };

       m_rollButton = findViewById(R.id.rollButton);
       m_rollButton.setOnClickListener(view -> Play());

       m_scoreChoiceDropdown = findViewById(R.id.spinnerScoreOption);
       m_scoreText = findViewById(R.id.scoreLabel);
       m_scoreChoiceText = findViewById(R.id.scoreChoiceInfo);

       m_scoreText.setText("Score: 0");
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    private void InitializeDropdown()
    {
        ArrayAdapter<ThirtyThrowsGame.ScoreChoice> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, m_game.getAvailableScoreChoices());
        m_scoreChoiceDropdown.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        m_scoreChoiceDropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        ThirtyThrowsGame.ScoreChoice selectedScore = ThirtyThrowsGame.ScoreChoice.valueOf("" + m_scoreChoiceDropdown.getSelectedItem());
                        ArrayList<ArrayList<Die>> diceCombinations = new ArrayList<>();
                        int scores = m_game.getScores(selectedScore, diceCombinations);
                        m_scoreChoiceText.setText(selectedScore + " gives you " + scores + " scores this round.");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) { }
                }
        );
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param diceCombinations
     */
    private void displayDiceCombinations(ArrayList<ArrayList<Die>> diceCombinations)
    {
        if(m_game.isRoundOver() && m_game.hasStarted() && !m_game.isRoundScored())
        {
            float dpScale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            int padding = (int) (2 * dpScale);
            int view_size = (int) (25 * dpScale);

            int lastChildIndex = 0;
            for(ArrayList<Die> dice : diceCombinations){
                ImageView img;
                for(Die die : dice){
                    img = new ImageView(this);
                    img.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, finishedDiceImages[die.getValue()]));
                    lastChildIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    private void Play() {
        if (m_game.isRoundOver()) {
            m_game.newRound();

            for (ImageView imageView : m_dice.keySet()) {
                RefreshDieImageView(imageView);
                imageView.setEnabled(true);
            }

            RefreshRollButtonText();

            m_scoreChoiceText.setText(null);
        } else {
            m_game.rollDice();
            RefreshAllDieImageViews();

            if (m_game.isRoundOver()) { }
            else {
                RefreshRollButtonText();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems fine to me. Can you please tell me if the selection doesn't work on all the items or just when you try to call the already selected item?

Comment: Nothing happens when I click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in

```
m_scoreChoiceText.setText("{selectedScore} gives you {scores} scores this round.");
```

in java you can't add variables within string like this you should concatenate the variables to be like that

```
m_scoreChoiceText.setText(selectedScore + " gives you " + scores + " scores this round.");
```

Comment: Mohammad, I am sorry. This didn't make a difference.

Comment: Did you try to debug, what happens when you add breakpoint in the `onItemSelected`?

Comment: Thought about this, and haven't checked yet. Got interrupted by something else here.

Comment: Please do it and write down the result

Comment: Does NOT work. I cannot click!

Comment: Can you update the question and add the whole activity code?

Comment: Sure, I can add the whole activity code. Not sure, if you will be able to find something.

Comment: That's strange because the code should run, Can you put breakpoints inside `InitializeDropdown` to see if it is called and listeners are added or not and inside the `OnItemSelectedListener` to see if it is fired or not

Comment: I found the error it was somewhere else. Fixed it. It was apparently entering an endless for-loop.

Comment: Glad to hear that